Does partitioning help when filter-reading key columns using a function?
I have this dataframe:
+------+
|my_col|
+------+
|202101|
|202209|
+------+

When writing as parquet file, I partition it based on column 'my_col', so I should get two partitions (two parquet files).
Then I will be reading the saved dataset, applying a filter.

Am I correct that Spark will not load data into the memory from the file containing my_col=202101 when applying the filter .filter("my_col >= 202201")?
Will the data from the parquet file containing my_col=202101 be loaded into the memory when applying the filter .filter("substring(my_col, 1, 4) >= 2022")?

In the latter case, I do not filter directly on key column values, but instead, a function is applied on the column. I wonder, if in this case partitioning helps to save on read time.

U can do an explain

not worthy of a separate answer (to Ahmed's), but this is only true for partition pruning where spark effectively executes it, when it's down at a field level (push down predicates / PushedFilters) only simple equality / in is allowed, functions are not.  This led to custom optimisations for Quality in order to avoid 'table scans'

Depending on your Spark and metastore versions, you may see the difference in what predicates are pushed down for evaluation to the metastore vs what Spark has to filter on the client side. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-33537

So I tried the below example to find out whether the function used in the filter is making any difference. Example:
data = [
    ("A ", "202201"),
    ("B ", "202209"),
    ("C ", "202210"),
    ("D ", "202301"),
]

columns = ["name", "dob"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df.write.partitionBy("dob").mode("overwrite").parquet("people.parquet")

people = spark.read.parquet("people.parquet")
people_filtered_without_function = people.filter("dob >= 202201")
people_filtered_with_function = people.filter("substring(dob, 1, 4) >= 2022")

people_filtered_without_function.explain()
people_filtered_with_function.explain()

Here are the results of the physical plans:

Without function


== Physical Plan ==
*(1) ColumnarToRow
+- FileScan parquet [name#7,dob#8] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/opt/spark/work-dir/people.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(dob#8), (dob#8 >= 202201)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: structname:string


With function


== Physical Plan ==
*(1) ColumnarToRow
+- FileScan parquet [name#7,dob#8] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/opt/spark/work-dir/people.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(dob#8), (cast(substring(cast(dob#8 as string), 1, 4) as int) >= 2022)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: structname:string

Note above the main difference being:
Partition Filter (Without) :

(dob#8 >= 202201)

Partition Filter (With) :

(cast(substring(cast(dob#8 as string), 1, 4) as int) >= 2022)

As you can see above the difference between the two methods. I would say this is what is happening:

Yes, Indeed the data will be filtered by spark and only the relevant files are read.
The plan also reflects the function usage in the filter. So I would assume only the overhead of the type casting and function application to be the main difference in performance here and not the actual filtering logic


Okay, I didn't know about PartitionFilters inside query plans. Thank you! It looks like it is well worth partitioning by the dob column even when downstream read-filters are using (basic) functions.
